# Did Adi Shankaracharya establish Akharas in addition to mathas?

Tags: history, adi-shankaracharya

Quite a few websites have popped up that claim Akharas were set up by Adi Shankaracharya. Some sites have even claimed that the Naga Sadhu order was organized into a mitary order by Adi Shankaracharya which I find preposterous.

I could not find reference to Akharas being associated with any mathas or sampradaya within mathas at time of Adi Shankaracharya in [Mahanushasanam](https://archive.org/details/MathamnayaSetuShardaBhasya)

Please point out to some valid sources that have traced the history of Akharas. Not looking for a western account written centuries later.

Comment: I don't think Shankaracharya established these mathas because foundation date differs for each matha.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - He did establish 4 mathas. The preface to the book i linked says mathas were established in 2500 yrs ago. But that has been stance of Kanchi peetha who claim mathas were established at that time and by a different Adi Shankara. But the remaining content of the book seems to be inline with the popular discourse of Adi Shankaracharya of 7th/8th century AD.